# Roots with html and stylus

Tags: javascript, html, workflow, stylus, roots-toolkit

For those who have used [roots](http://roots.cx) before, you know it uses jade, stylus, and coffee script as it's default stack.

The docs give some overview of using html, css, and pure javascript instead of the compiled languages, but mentions nothing of being able to pick and choose.

For my use, I only need html and js, but want to use stylus. Anyone with experience using roots know how I would do about setting this up?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually super simple. All you have to do is change the file extension from `.css` to `.styl` and it should work. You can even set up your own default template that uses this setup. Here are two links that explain templates:

- http://roots.cx/docs/#templates
- http://roots.cx/docs/man.html#TEMPLATE

That's for Roots V2. It's worth noting that Roots V3 exists in the form of a [pre-release](https://github.com/jenius/roots/releases/tag/v3.0.0-rc.7) - just go to the repo here: https://github.com/jenius/roots/tree/v3

Roots V3 has seen a lot of Root's internal components separated out into their own independent modules, notably [Accord](https://github.com/jenius/accord) for compilation, [Ship](https://github.com/carrot/ship) for deployment, [Charge](https://github.com/carrot/charge) for server management, [Sprout](https://github.com/carrot/sprout) for templating and Roots V3 even includes a highly robust [plugin interface](http://roots.readthedocs.org/en/latest/extensions.html).

In terms of compiling different kinds of files, there won't be much difference in a V3 project as there is in a V2 project, it's still just a case of changing file extensions as far as I'm aware.

All the docs you need are right here: http://roots.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html

Comment: Hey thanks! Yeah I kind of forgot I still had the question open and got in touch with the devs about it. I'll mark this as correct and give you the credit :)